# Determining probability by sampling

Tags: probability, statistics

I am a programmer and I have a function that is not perfect and can sometimes fail for various uncontrollable reasons.
I want to know what is the probability of it succeeding.
My naive approach so far is to run it 100 times and divide the success amount by 100.
The problem is that 100 is not a good number for every use case and I do not know how to determine the number I need.
In scientific sources I sometimes see probabilities like 95%+/-0.5% and I do not manage to find how to determine what is the error range of my measurement.
What is the way to tackle this problem?
My motivation for this is that if I can compare the success rate of functions,  I can try to improve my function.

Comment: Well, depending on what you are doing, $100$ might not be big enough.  Perhaps you are afraid of rare, catastrophic fails.  In which case you need to do enough trials so that you'd expect to see one of those.  As to confidence ranges, those require modeling.  You have to make assumptions about your function and the distribution of errors.

Comment: @lulu all failures have the same outcome for me. Is it possible to get confidence ranges by treating my function as a boolean random generator with an unknown fixed probability?

Comment: Well, I think what you are saying is "assume that there is a parameter $p$ such that the function fails on a given trial with parameter $p$, independently of all other trials".  That's certainly a standard assumption!  And, yes, you can use it to get a confidence interval.  After all, if $p=.1$ then there is only a very, very small chance that you only observe $3$ fails out of $100$ (as an example).

Comment: @lulu: I am aiming to get the success rate of my function above 90%, 95%, 99%, etc. Can I use my target to calculate the amount of runs I need?

Comment: I don't understand.  The success rate is whatever it is...nothing you've said suggests that you have any ability to alter that. I thought you were asking if you could *measure* the success rate.  That you can do, at least approximately.  If you run a million trials you really should have an excellent idea what the success rate is.

Comment: @lulu: I can change the trial to try to make it more successful. But then I have the problem of how do I know whether it is more successful? That is how I got to need to measure the success rate.

Comment: Ok...but you don't give any information relevant to changing the rate.  In any case, to measure it, just do a lot of trials.  In practice, that should be fine.  I wouldn't do $100$...unless the trials are expensive.  Too small a number.  But of course, I don't know the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is interesting because (presumably) your function $f(x)$ is deterministic given its inputs $x$ -- unless it is a random algorithm, in which case it is deterministic given $x$ and $\epsilon$, which is the random seed(s) you are using to initialize the pseudorandom number generator(s).

Either way, I think that you are treating the success and failure rate of your function as a property of the function vs a property of the inputs + function.

In machine learning, one way your once-excellent ML model can start to lose accuracy is distribution drift: the distribution of each feature changes from that used during training, which will generally degrade performance/accuracy.

Therefore, modeling your function as a Bernoulli($p$) variable assumes the distribution of inputs to your function will be stationary/stable.

I think you'll be better served by doing the reverse of this. Stratify your inputs by whether they produced a success or failure and then fit a classifier to that labeled data to identify what combinations of inputs are causing the failure.

---

That being said, if you do want to estimate some form of "long run" success rate then we can estimate an adequate number of samples.

Let $X$ have a Bernoulli(p) distribution, so $P(X=\text{success})=p$

The mean/expected value of $X$ (written $E[X]$) is just $p$ and the variance is $p(1-p)$.

Let's say we test our function $N$ times, where the outcome of test $i$ is modeled as $X_i$, and calculate the sample success rate $\hat p_N$:

$$\hat p_N = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N X_i}{N}$$

How variable is $\hat p_N$ (i.e., if we repeated our experiment a large number $M$ times, each time calculating $\hat p_N$, what would be the variance of $\hat p_N$)

Let's assume the $X_i$ are independent, then we get:

$$Var[\hat p_N] = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N p(1-p)}{N^2} = \frac{Np(1-p)}{N^2} = \frac{p(1-p)}{N}$$

We can calculate the probability that its error $\varepsilon_N:=|\hat p_n - p|$ will be greater than some number $\eta>0$ (using [Chebyshev's Inequality)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality):

$$P\left(|\hat p_n - p| \geq \eta\right) \leq \frac{Var[\hat p_N]}{\eta^2} = \frac{p(1-p)}{N\eta^2}$$

The variance of our estimator is maximized at $p=\frac12$.
Assuming $p=\frac12$, we get:

$$P\left(\left|\hat p_n - \frac12 \right| \geq \eta\right) \leq \frac{1}{4N\eta^2}:=k_N$$

Using this, we can then find an adequate sample size. Let's say we want to have a sample large enough that there is only a $k$ probability of being off by more than $\eta \ll 1$ (usually $k_n \in [0.05,0.01]$). The (likely conservative) sample size $N$ will be a function of $k,\eta$:

$$N(k,\eta) = \frac{1}{4k\eta^2}$$

For example:

If we want to be at least 99% confident that we no more than $0.01$ off from the true success probabiltiy, then we need:

$$N(.01,.01) = \frac{1}{4(.01)(.01)^2 } = 250,000 \text{ samples }$$

Comment: In the example in the end, did you miss squaring η?

Comment: @Daniel yes! my mistake -- correct, square it, so just a few more samples ;)

Answer (score 1):

Compute the 95% confidence interval for a Bernoulli random variable.  For details on how to do that, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4756/2921 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval.